# Why are the values of an array treated as final or "effectively final" when accessed from an anonymous inner class or lambda?

Tags: java, java-8

I was reading about functional interfaces (https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces), and about a `Supplier<T>`, it said this:

> Another use case for the Supplier is defining a logic for sequence generation. To demonstrate it, let’s use a static Stream.generate method to create a Stream of Fibonacci numbers:

```
int[] fibs = {0, 1};
Stream<Integer> fibonacci = Stream.generate(() -> {
    int result = fibs[1];
    int fib3 = fibs[0] + fibs[1];
    fibs[0] = fibs[1];
    fibs[1] = fib3;
    return result;
});
```

> The function that is passed to the Stream.generate method implements
>   the Supplier functional interface. Notice that to be useful as a
>   generator, the Supplier usually needs some sort of external state. In
>   this case, its state is comprised of two last Fibonacci sequence
>   numbers.
>
> To implement this state, we use an array instead of a couple of
>   variables, **because all external variables used inside the lambda have
>   to be effectively final**.

I understand why variables need to be final within a lamdba or an anonymnous class, what I don't understand is why values of an array are "effectively final".

I have illustrated this with an example below:

```
final boolean run = true;
executor.execute(() -> {
    while (run) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Here `run` is final, so it cannot be modified after defining the lamdba. This makes sense to me.

```
boolean[] runArr = { true };
executor.execute(() -> {
    while (run) {
        // do something
    }
});
runArr[0] = false;
```

Here `run` is not final, as I am allowed to modify the contents of `runArr[0]`. This seems like it could produce unexpected behaviour, and could cause concurrency problems. My question is, why does the compiler allow you to do this? Is this not breaking the rule of final only variables?

Comment: They're not effectively final. They're not local variables in the first place, so they can't be effectively final.

Comment: “*because all external variables used inside the lambda have to be effectively final.*” is just wrong. Only local variables must be final or effectively final. Array elements are not local variables. The same applies to instance field and static fields.

Comment: Besides that, using `Stream.generate` for Fibonacci numbers, is a bad example either. The sequence of Fibonacci numbers has an order, but `Stream.generate` produces an *unordered* stream. And yes, the way it uses mutable state would lead to concurrency problems if you use this stream with parallel processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values stored in the array aren't (effectively) final (and they don't need to be)

The reference to the array itself, however, is effectively final.

For "normal" (primitive) variables, the variable technically holds the actual value.
For arrays (and Objects) the variable technically holds a pointer to the first element of the array (or to the start of the objects data).
So when using an array inside a lambda expression the variable (the pointer to the array) is effectively final, but the content of the array (where the pointer is pointing to) can still be changed.

Comment: I suspected it might have something to do with pointers, but wasn't aware of this distinction when storing a variable (I thought it would have still been treated as a pointer). That clears everything up, thanks a lot!